# .NET form not loading inside thickbox window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, css, thickbox

I'm working with a website built in .net,

I have a very simple popup box (thickbox) which works fine up until my developer puts the .net contact form within the popup.

The problem is that the form no longer shows up inside the thickbox, has anybody experience this before?

Its not like its even calling data from elsewhere, all the content is on the page in a hidden div that when requested the javascript shows the popup.

My popup window looks like the following...

```
<div id="hidForm">
    <asp:Panel ID="PL_Im_Popup" runat="server" >
    .net stuff here doesnt load!
    </asp:Panel>
    The stuff outside of the .net panel works fine 
</div>
```

---

My entire code is...

```
<div id="hidForm">
<asp:Panel ID="PL_Im_Popup" runat="server" >
    <h3>Our Discreet Service</h3>
    <p>To request a phone call from a Correlate Search Consultant simply fill out the form below. Discretion is of upmost importance to our Consultants.</p>
    <ul id="hidFormLab">
    <li><span class="formLabel">Your Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TB_Name" runat="server" CssClass="formet"></asp:TextBox></li>

        <li><span class="formLabel">Your Job Title <span class="asterisk">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TB_JobTitle" runat="server" CssClass="formet"></asp:TextBox></li>

        <li><span class="formLabel">Your Email <span class="asterisk">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TB_Email" runat="server" CssClass="formet"></asp:TextBox></li>

        <li><span class="formLabel">Your Telephone Number <span class="asterisk">*</span></span><asp:TextBox ID="TB_PhoneNo" runat="server" CssClass="formet"></asp:TextBox></li>

        <li><span class="formLabel">Upload your CV</span><asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="upcv" /></li>

        <li><span class="formLabel">What day would you prefer to be contacted on</span><asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_ContactDay" runat="server" CssClass="ddown">
            <asp:ListItem>Monday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Thursday</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Friday</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></li>

       <li><span class="formLabel">If you would prefer to be contacted at a specific time,please let us know</span><asp:DropDownList
           ID="DDL_Time" runat="server" CssClass="ddown">
           <asp:ListItem>Morning</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Afternoon</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Evening</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList></li>

       <li><asp:ImageButton ID="IB_Submit" runat="server" CssClass="submitformbtn" 
               ImageUrl="~/_includes/images/buttons/submit.jpg" onclick="IB_Submit_Click" /></li>
    </ul>

</asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: You still need the `<form runat="server">` for this to work

Comment: What do you mean sorry David?

Comment: Is that the full code for your pop-up? in it's own page? maybe you should post a little more code.

Comment: This full code is the entire code for the popup? I'm guessing you need an `@Page` directing in there as well as a `form runat="server"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed `<form runat="server">` for this to work, Thanks @David

Comment: Please edit your answer to put the ` character at the start and end of the tag (otherwise the tag is invisible).  I would do it, but it would be less than 6 characters, and would also need peer reviewing